# How can glossaries handle the article 'a' or 'an' before abbreviations?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I am wondering how would glossaries handle the article 'a' that comes before abbreviations. For e.g.,

> Fox Mulder is **a Federal Bureau of Investigation** special agent educated at Oxford who believes in the existence of extraterrestrials and a government conspiracy to hide the truth regarding them.

However, if I use glossaries to abbreviate FBI later, it would read:

> Dana Scully is **an FBI** special agent, a medical doctor, and scientist who is Mulder's partner. In contrast to his credulity, Scully is a skeptic, basing her beliefs on scientific explanations.

If I move the second statement up it would read:

> Scully is **an Federal Bureau of Investigation** special agent, a medical doctor, and scientist who is Mulder's partner. In contrast to his credulity, Scully is a skeptic, basing her beliefs on scientific explanations.

How can this be prevented with glossaries?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newacronym{fbi}{FBI}{Federal Bureau of Investigation}
\begin{document}
Fox Mulder is a \gls{fbi} special agent educated at Oxford
who believes in the existence of extraterrestrials and a
government conspiracy to hide the truth regarding them.

Dana Scully is an \gls{fbi} special agent, a medical doctor,
and scientist who is Mulder's partner. In contrast to his
credulity, Scully is a skeptic, basing her beliefs on
scientific explanations.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `glossaries-prefix` which is supplied with the `glossaries` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries-prefix}
\newacronym[
    prefixfirst={a\ },% prefix used on first use
    prefix={an\ }% prefix used on subsequent use
]
{fbi}{FBI}{Federal Bureau of Investigation}
\begin{document}
Fox Mulder is \pgls{fbi} special agent educated at Oxford
who believes in the existence of extraterrestrials and a
government conspiracy to hide the truth regarding them.

Dana Scully is \pgls{fbi} special agent, a medical doctor,
and scientist who is Mulder's partner. In contrast to his
credulity, Scully is a skeptic, basing her beliefs on
scientific explanations.
\end{document}
```

[image: Fox Mulder is a Federal Bureau of Investigation (FBI) special agent educated at Oxford who believes in the existence of extraterrestrials and a government conspiracy to hide the truth regarding them. Dana Scully is an FBI special agent, a medical doctor, and scientist who is Mulder’s partner. In contrast to his credulity, Scully is a skeptic, basing her beliefs on scientific explanations.]

The `glossaries-prefix` package loads `glossaries` and adds four new keys: `prefix`, `prefixplural`, `prefixfirst` and `prefixfirstplural`. You can determine if the `prefix` field has been provided for a particular entry with `\ifglshasprefix{`*label*`}{`*true*`}{`*false*`}`. This tests if the `prefix` field is empty. There are similar commands for the other prefix fields.

The command `\pgls`¹ has the same syntax as `\gls` and performs the same test as in Ulrike's answer, so `\pgls{fbi}` is essentially the same as

```
\ifglsused{fbi}{\glsentryprefix{fbi}}{\glsentryprefixfirst{fbi}}\gls{fbi}
```

but is more convenient to use.

Note that there's no space automatically inserted between the prefix and `\gls` to allow for things like `prefix={l'}` in French. If you want a second set of prefixes, then you'll have to add the fields manually using `\glsaddkey` and define a command similar to `\pgls`.

---

¹ Similarly for the upper case and plural variants. See the `glossaries` user manual for the complete list of provided commands.

Comment: One might want to refer to “the FBI”.

Comment: @egreg In that case one would just write `the \gls{fbi}` since then it doesn't matter whether or not the abbreviation has been expanded.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot prefix versions of the `\ac` commands would be very appreciated ;)

Comment: Minimal version would be something like `\let\pac\pgls
\let\Pac\Pgls
\let\pacp\pglspl
\let\Pacp\Pglspl`

Answer (score 7):

You can test if an entry has been used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newacronym{fbi}{FBI}{Federal Bureau of Investigation}
\begin{document}
Fox Mulder is \ifglsused{fbi}{an}{a} \gls{fbi} special agent educated at Oxford
who believes in the existence of extraterrestrials and a
government conspiracy to hide the truth regarding them.

Dana Scully is \ifglsused{fbi}{an}{a} \gls{fbi} special agent, a medical doctor,
and scientist who is Mulder's partner. In contrast to his
credulity, Scully is a skeptic, basing her beliefs on
scientific explanations.
\end{document}
```

[image]